# convert value of Material Color to Hex Code

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to convert value of Material Color to Hex Code in flutter, I have been trying for a while now but i just cant work around it.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is a utils package that contains a ColorUtils class that can convert hex to int and int to hex. That can be used to create the Flutter colors or a HEX value from the Flutter color.

Github: https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils

PuDev: https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils

Install :

```
basic_utils: ^2.0.0
```

Example :

```dart
Color color = Color(ColorUtils.hexToInt("#FFFFFF"));
String hex = ColorUtils.intToHex(color.value);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a package for functionality that exists in Dart by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Take the integer representation and convert it into a hexadecimal string:

```
String hexCode = '#${color.value.toRadixString(16).padLeft(8, '0')}';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Color colorPrimary = const Color(0xFF32ad79);
int hexCode = colorPrimary.value
```